# Mountaintop sea - Characteristics regarding tides, outflow and microclimate

Tags: internal-consistency, water-bodies

In an Earth-like world, with a single Moon similar to ours, there is a mountain that is 1.000 meters high. 
On top of that mountain there is a crater with ca. 100 Km radius and 100 m of maximum depth. 
That crater was filled with rain water (it stands on a very rainy spot) during centuries and now it became a sea. 
Since the only water replenishment of this sea is from rain, it has become very salty (*)
There is now a city built on the shores of said sea, almost at the sea level.

Now, for my storytelling, I would like to know three things:

1. Would this sea have waves and tides?
2. How could this sea drain its waters without flooding the nearby city?
3. Would there be nocturnal fogs generated by this sea?

(*) ***EDIT***: As a person in the comments has insightfully deduced, I'm describing an endorheic basin. People have pointed out that this may be tricky to accomplish. If you have answers or comments regarding the salinity of this sea, please post them [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/68121/basin-on-a-mountaintop-how-to-keep-the-water-salty).

**Now please, I urge people on this thread to stay on topic and answer the questions I actually posed.**

Comment: " Since the only water replenishment of this sea is from rain, it has become very salty " ..? typically rainwater isn't ... salty?

Comment: @Zxyrra The question appears to be trying to describe an [endorheic basin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endorheic_basin), but getting some of the cause and effect mixed up.

Comment: I'm rather amused by 1,000 meters being thought of as "high altitude" :-)

Comment: @sevensideddie: You are absolutely correct.

Comment: @jamesqf: I meant high altitude as in being on a mountaintop. Mind you, climate and geography are the worldbuilding topics I have more trouble with, since they fall outside my field of expertise. Hence, the purpose of this site, no? People will eventually ask stupid questions, and that's OK

Comment: As long as there is wind, there will be waves.

Comment: Compare the world's highest navigable lake, 3,812 m up: Lake Titicaca.

Comment: In *Magic: the Gathering*, I'm rather fond of the Ninth Edition version of Sea's Claim http://magiccards.info/9e/en/97.html, which has the flavor text “‘Who's the crazy one now!?’ —Torgle, mountaintop boatmaker”.  Aquitect's Will http://magiccards.info/lw/en/52.html asserts that the merfolk can make sea go anywhere, even to the top of a mointain.  For your question 1, both cards show that such a sea has waves; the name of Tideshaper Mystic http://magiccards.info/lw/en/93.html suggests that it has tides too.

Comment: For question 2, the Island cards of Ravnica http://magiccards.info/rav/en/291.html http://magiccards.info/rav/en/292.html shows parts of the city of the city planet built over the sea; Kamigawa also has buildings over sea http://magiccards.info/chk/en/293.html .

Comment: @PedroGabriel The title of your question states "is this plausible?" which suggests you're looking for feedback on the plausibility of your lake idea, but you're rejecting answers which talk about that plausibility. It's not unreasonable for someone to think you wanted feedback on the idea itself given the title.  I suggest rewording the question title to make it more clear exactly what you do want.

Comment: @barbecue: The title of the question doesn't excuse the reading of the question proper. Still, I've reworded the title.

Comment: Your lake will not be very salty, without feeder rivers the only source of minerals is dissolving the lake bottom, which will be too slow to build up significant salt. Normal weathering will errode an outlet before that happens. If you need it to be salty you will need tom give the underlying rock a huge salt content but that will make it easier to weather away.

Comment: Why would an outlet flood the city? if its on the side of a mountain then there is no basin to flood? Of course once an outlet forms you will not have a lake for long.

Comment: @jamesqf: for a 30000 sq. km lake, 1000 m is quite high altitude. Generally the terrain at such elevation is quite ragged and not suitable for extended water bodies.The only such large lake on Earth is lake Victoria (at 1100 m); lake Tanganyika (at 700 m) comes second.

Comment: @jamesqf I was a bit confused at the thought of a 1 meter high "mountain" being considered "high altitude" ;)

Comment: @AlexP: Sure, but Victoria &c are not "mountaintop" lakes.  In recent prehistory, there are the pluvial lakes of the Great Basin (Lahontan & Bonneville) with highstands around 1500 m, and of course there's Tahoe at ~2000 m.  I quite agree about the inherent difficulty of having large lakes on mountaintops: it's just the idea of thinking of 1000 m as "high elevation" that amused me.   Oregon's Crater Lake would be about the closest thing to a sizeable mountaintop lake, and it's nowhere near as large as what the OP wants.  Nor is it salty.

Comment: @PedroGabriel Interestingly, another user just recently downvoted multiple answers because they answered the body of the question and not the title, which were inconsistent.  Personally I feel the body is more important, but not everyone agrees. The best solution is to ensure they are consistent, so nobody can complain either way.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

- Salt.

  Rain water is not salty at all; in unpolluted places it is the closest thing to distilled water to be found in nature. Lakes become salty only if they have no outlets; since this lake is in a very rainy region it must necessarily have outlets. It won't be salty, it will be a fresh water lake. I cannot think of any salt water lake in a very rainy area. The key to making a salty lake is to have no outlets, so that water loss is only by evaporation. Very rainy + high altitude + high evaporation make for a strange combination.
- Tides.

  I'm afraid that there is no way to have tides in a lake only 200 km across. It's simply much too small. However, it can have [seiches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seiche) (and it [most likely will](http://geo.msu.edu/extra/geogmich/seiches.htm)). (OK, *no tides* is not strictly true; you may expect to see tidal amplitudes of about 1 cm or so.)
- Drainage.

  The lake, being in a rainy region, has a constant influx of water. The water must go somewhere: it will flow out of the lake as a river. The outlet may be very spectacular -- see [Blue Nile falls](http://www.thousandwonders.net/Blue+Nile+Falls) at the exit of [Lake Tana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Tana). (As an aside, Lake Tana is quite similar to the lake in the [*original* question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/revisions/68006/1), but it is not as deep. The lake in the *revised* question looks *very much* like [Lake Victoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Victoria).)
- Fog.

  Depends on climate. Lake-effect fog forms when the air is cooler than the water; for example, at temperate latitudes cold autumn mornings produce fog out of every little water surface. I would say that the high altitude makes morning fogs quite likely.

Edit: The question has been edited to specify that the lake lies in an endorheic basin. This contradicts the "very rainy" region. An endorheic lake in a very rainy region is not going to remain endorheic for long; the water level will increase until it will go over a sill or the lake will erode an outlet; especially a lake at an elevation significantly higher than the surrounding plain.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, AlexP. Just one thing... I just noticed a mistake in my question. The sea has 100 Km radius, not diameter.

Comment: Also, I thought that the rain would not be suficient to create a fresh water sea... I thought that the influx for that would mandate rivers, which this sea doesn't have.

Comment: @PedroGabriel: Changed the answer to indicate Lake Victoria as a very similar real-geography lake. If fits very well.

Comment: Concerning salt, it's also important that it's not being fed by any rivers - water entering the lake would not have a chance to pick up salt and bring it to the lake.

Comment: @RobWatts: So a constant influx of water from rivers will actually increase the salinity of the sea?

Comment: Lake Victoria is very very much like this lake. Surface elevation 1100m. Maximum depth 83 m. Surface area 68000 sq. km (about double than the lake in the question). Fed by [rainfall over a small area](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/Victoria/victoria2.php).

Comment: @PedroGabriel: A lake remains fresh as long as it has an outlet; the lake accumulates salt if water is lost only by evaporation (because water evaporates and salt doesn't, so in time the concentration of salt increases). Examples: Salt Lake, Caspian Sea, Dead Sea. Salty lakes are tricky, because they live at the narrow edge where the influx of water exactly compensates evaporation. See how the Dead Sea has shrunk in recent decades.

Comment: "No tides" is a harsh verdict, you'll certainly be able to detect a variation on the magnitude of ~one centimeter. The mediterranean certainly has (minor) tides, and it's just ~ten times as large.

Comment: @Karl: Tides which are much smaller than small waves are of no practical importance. There are places in the Mediterranean with remarcably large tide amplitudes, the best known being Gabes in Tunisia with tidal amplitudes up to 1.5 m. The Mediterranean is also much larger - 3.75 million sq. km instead of about 30000 sq. km. The Black Sea, which is only about 15 times larger than this lake, has negligible tides, not exceeding 5 or 6 cm amplitude.

Comment: That's what I said: Ten times the diameter. ;-)

Comment: You can have bigger tides if you make the moon bigger.  Of course, this means that oceanic tides will be even more significant...

Comment: I took liberty to add a link to original question, for people that are not accustomed to looking at revision history on Stack Exchange. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: The basic reason for large tidal ranges in some places on earth is because of bodies of  *deep* water, which happen to be the right size so that the water can slosh back and forth like water in a bath tub, with each "slosh" taking just the right amount of time to build up the amplitude (i.e a bit more than 12 hours). High tides are a side effect of this *along coastlines* where the water has nowhere else to go - e.g. the Bay of Fundy, or the Bristol Channel and river Severn in the UK, at opposite sides of the Atlantic. This can't happen in a "small" landlocked lake.

Comment: You can get an endorheic basin in a "very rainy" area if the drainage area is very small.  For example, Crater Lake in Oregon has no outlet, despite receiving a meter and a half of rainfall every year.

Comment: @Mark: The [water balance of Crater Lake](https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/1992/of92-505/) show that it receives about 224 cm/year of rain, out of which only about 85 cm/year evaporate; 139 cm/year are lost to subsurface seepage mainly [going to the Wood River](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crater_Lake).

Answer (score 14):

One big problem that nobody seems to have noticed:

This lake is on a mountaintop.  That means its catchment area is little more than the lake itself—any other water goes down the outside of the mountain, not into the lake.

Thus you have in effect a giant-sized rain puddle that never dries up.  I have a hard time picturing this.

As others have said, the normal means of making a salt lake can't work here.  However, I don't consider this a showstopper, let's make a salt lake by a different method:

Long, long ago there was a massive magma intrusion in the area, perhaps there was some actual vulcanism but that's irrelevant.  A huge area of granite was formed.  As the millenia went by the material above this granite eroded away.  (Granite only forms when the magma cools very slowly—which means it must be deep.  The same material on the surface forms basalt—not nearly as hard.  There's also an intermediate between these whose name I have forgotten in the decades since school.)

Now a supervolcano erupts, blowing a huge caldera—the size of your lake.  This is lowlands, though, not a mountain.  A salt lake forms, then it's opened to the sea and a fairly small amount of ordinary sedimentary rock is laid down on top.

Now the area is uplifted to your desired height, the wind chips away at the soft rock on top but it doesn't eat it all—the salt layer is still underneath.  It reaches your desired height and the climate turns rainy for some reason.  Now you have a basically freshwater lake on top of salt with a thin and damaged barrier—at some point the water reaches the salt and dissolves enough to make it salty.

If you will accept a somewhat greater deviation from your description:

While this is one mountain it's actually the foothills of an even higher mountain range that has arisen (uplift and vulcanism are often found together)  The actual catchment area of the lake includes a decent chunk of those mountains, the water is flowing underground into your lake and through the salt.

Comment: I like this answer, because it explains how most salt lakes / rivers form up, trought underground salty passages.  Salty caverns of cardona, where water still flows in small, very salty, and super cold, river streams. https://www.eyeonspain.com/userfiles/image/mac75/parc_06.jpg

Comment: Than you for your answer. Unfortunately it is off topic. As soon as I can, I'll post another question regarding the saltiness of this lake and I ask you to copy-paste this answer there, for it might be the chosen answer.

Comment: _"Thus you have in effect a giant-sized rain puddle that never dries up. I have a hard time picturing this."_ I don't quite follow this. Where do you think the water cycle "begins" on land? Our water sources are ultimately replenished by rainfall, and always have been.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Our water sources are replenished mostly by water runoff not by direct rain. Direct rain only will have a hard time keeping up with evaporation.

Comment: @John: Gravity requires that the water system is primarily replenished by rainfall, especially for sources at relatively high altitude (i.e. most of them)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit rainfall falling on a march larger basin than the body of water, this is not the case here, the drainage basin is the same size as the lake, which means it is receiving very little incoming water. Normally lakes are fed by rain falling on a land area hundreds of times the lakes surface area.

Comment: This isn't as big a problem as you think. The catchment of Lake Victoria is only 3x the size of the lake itself. So its not hard to imagine an enormous crater (Ngorogoro is 8,000 km, so thats a start) where 1/4 of the crater is covered by a lake. Victoria itself is in a crater-like depression surrounded by the high mountains of the two branches of the African Rift. As a bonus, if it is warm year-round, and the surrounding mountains are high, most of the lakes evaporation will be fed back into the lake.

Comment: @loren pechtel: As predicted, I've posted a separate question regarding the salinity of the sea. Please follow the link on the edit in the OP.

Comment: @kingledion Yes lake victoria would be a good model.

Comment: @kingledion: Re Victoria being " surrounded by the high mountains", that rather precludes it being the OP's requested mountain TOP lake, doesn't it?

Comment: @jamesqf High mountains in this case really only means higher than Lake Victoria. Go north or south from Victoria and you won't ever climb more than a few hundred meters of the lake surface height. There are high mountainst East and West, but those are optional, I suppose. Plus, I think you are taking the OP a little too literally when he uses the word mountaintop.

Answer (score 13):

A lake of 100 km radius will have an area of 31,000 km$^2$. That is [about the size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lakes_by_area) of Tangyanika or Baikal, or a little bigger than Lake Erie.

If it were 100m deep, then its volume would be about 3,100 km$^3$. That is [about the volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lakes_by_volume) of Lake Huron or Lake Victoria.

[Lake Victoria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Victoria) is larger by surface area than your lake, about the same by volume, and has a surface elevation of 1133m. So you are basically talking about Lake Victoria in this question, except salty. The closest high altitude salt lake I can think of is [Issyk Kul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Issyk-Kul), at about 1/5 the surface area, 1/2 the volume (its very deep) and at elevation 1607 meters. However, if the water inflow to Lake Victoria dropped, it could easily become an endoheric lake due it its massive surface area and high evaporation. In that case, it would become salty over time.

Lake Victoria does not have tides (of any appreciable size), and drains to the sea through the Nile River. It can generate noctural fogs, but more importantly it generates huge areas of rainfall. There are thousands of square kilometers of savannah turned to rainforest conditions on both its East and Western shore.

Comment: Up-voted for answering the questions in the topic.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be looking at [Lake Bonneville](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Bonneville) and [Lake Lahontan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Lahontan). The [Great Salt Lake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Salt_Lake) is a real salty lake at 1283 m at 4400 km2 that is a remnant of Lake Bonneville.

The lakes mentioned don't drain, they don't/didn't have tides, I don't believe that Bonneville was salty, but lower lake levels were, and the Great Salt Lake does produce fog.

Comment: Bonneville did drain, and rather dramatically :-)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonneville_flood  The remnants of the pluvial lakes of the Great Basin vary: the Great Salt Lake is, of course, salty, as is the Bonneville Salt Flat.  Mono Lake is also quite salty, but Walker & Pyramid lakes are only slightly so.  The playas (or at least the ones I'm familiar with) that are usually dry are more alkaline than salt.

Answer (score 0):

You have a really fundamental problem with wanting a mountaintop lake of that size.  Mountains, as you may or may not have noticed, are kind of pointy on the top, which means there's not a lot of room up there to put a lake.  Also non-volcanic mountains tend to occur in fairly linear bands - ranges, IOW - which again limits the area on top.

I can think of maybe 4 ways to get something vaguely like the lake you want.

1) A volcano which experienced a catastrophic eruption, leaving a caldera which is then filled by a lake.  Oregon's Crater Lake, formed by the eruption of Mt. Mazama about 7500 years ago, is the classic example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crater_Lake  The problem here is that there are limits on the size of a stratovolcano, which means that the resulting lake isn't going to be that much bigger than Crater Lake.

2) A valley between mountain ranges which is dammed somehow.  Lake Tahoe is a good example of this: the valley formed by uplift/downdrop between the Sierra Nevada & Carson Range was dammed by volcanic eruptions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Tahoe#Geology  The problem here is that it isn't on the mountain TOP, and is surrounded by a larger catchment basin that feeds it through rivers & streams.

3) Endorheic lakes, like Lakes Lahontan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lake_Lahontan & Bonnevile of the Pleistocene Great Basin.  These can be at the required elevation, but aren't located on mountain tops, but within higher elevation plateaus.  (The lowest points in the Great Basin are more than 1000 elevation.)  Lahontan had a high elevation of ~1500 m, but is surrounded by (and enclosed as islands) mountains of 3000 m and more.  They also have large catchment basins, feeding them from rivers & streams.

4) Meteor crater lake, like Manicouagan: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manicouagan_crater  These aren't going to be on mountaintops, either.  If the impacting body did happen to land on top of a mountain, that mountain would be removed. along with much of the underlying rock.  One large enough to form a lake of the size you want would likely fill with magma to about sea level, maybe below, e.g. large lunar craters.

Bottom line is that AFAIK there's no way to get a lake meeting all your requirements.

As for your questions, #1 has been adequately answered already. For #2 you have two choices, either the water rises until it finds an outlet (e.g. Tahoe), or it's endorheic because enough water evaporates before the level rises to an outlet.  #3 depends on your local climate, e.g. the Tahoe Basin and Great Basin valleys can be filled with winter fog/low clouds (as it is today), but be clear in summer.